# Python Selenium - How do you click on every row element for column of web table?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-testing

This may be a two part question so forgive me if this isn't well written:

I'm trying to get my WebDriver to go to the nba team stats page: http://stats.nba.com/teams/traditional/#!?sort=W_PCT&dir=-1

[Table Image for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQAUC.jpg)

and then click the linked FGM numbers in the table. This should open a new tab in the background. So far I'm completely lost how I should be approaching this.

I'm thinking:

- I need a way to count the rows
- Then I need to tell the WebDriver to
  loop/click through elements in the FGM column for the row count

I'm sure I can get the data with BeautifulSoup but I'm trying to practice with Selenium and working with tables/links that can vary in length. Any leads are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
web_driver = webdriver.Firefox()

web_driver.get("http://stats.nba.com/teams/traditional/#!?sort=W_PCT&dir=-1")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
team_links = webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath("//body//td[contains(@class, 'first')]/a")

for link in team_links:
    actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(link).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Comment: So this looks like it's going down the first five items on the Team column continuously and sometimes pop ups the side menu. Where did you get 'first' from? This is definitely on the right track but I just want to be able to understand how to specify the column in the table. Thank you!

Comment: Saul, It is the <td> class I was using. I think you just need to tune to use the elements you specifically need.

Comment: Okay so I've tried to do this and I just can't figure it out. For some reason... it's always repeating link in the new tabs created. For example I have a list of two elements and use the ActionChains to click on them THREE tabs are opened where the first element is clicked on twice.Do you have any insights?